# finding syntax error in mysql if condition

Tags: mysql, syntax

With the following sql code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER yirmi_test BEFORE UPDATE ON `orders`
FOR EACH ROW
IF ((OLD.`product_price_currency` != "") AND (NEW.`product_price_currency` = "")) THEN
signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Erasing currency';
END IF;
```

I get the following error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are fine. Just wrap with the following begin and end `delimiter` block. It passed a 1064 test for me:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER yirmi_test BEFORE UPDATE ON `orders`
FOR EACH ROW
IF ((OLD.`product_price_currency` != "") AND (NEW.`product_price_currency` = "")) THEN
signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Erasing currency';
END IF;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Read the bottom of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905535) concerning delimiters. It is trivial, but it can waste hours.